# sinatra app doesn't start on run

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10/Ruby 1.9.2

Whatever I do, I can't get a sinatra app to start on my local machine.

**hello.rb:**

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

"$ ruby hello.rb" and "$ ruby -rubygems hello.rb" both result in a new prompt with no action taken.

Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue in `Sinatra 1.0` running on `Ruby 1.9.2`; it has been fixed in `Sinatra 1.1` which [is just around the corner](http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/tree/1.1.a).

Fix it with `enable :run`:

```
require 'sinatra'
enable :run

get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Another issue you might run into with the `Ruby 1.9.2` + `Sinatra 1.0` stack concerns the change of the default load path for Ruby scripts in `Ruby 1.9.2`, which doesn't include the current directory, therefore views don't work as expected by default, fix it with:

```
set :views, File.dirname(FILE) + "/views"
```

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade to Sinatra 1.1.