# Sinatra requires restart

Tags: ruby, sinatra

*I'm just getting started with Sinatra. I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 on Ubuntu. After my first [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973402/sinatra-app-doesnt-start-on-run), I've run into another one:*

When I follow the simple sample application instructions at [sinatra.rubyforge.org/doc/](http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/doc/), I modify my source file, but the changes aren't apparent until I restart Sinatra - even though the tutorial mentions there is no need to restart.

**How can I edit my source and view the results without having to restart Sinatra every time?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Sinatra to auto-reload the file after each change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247125/how-to-get-sinatra-to-auto-reload-the-file-after-each-change)

Comment: I posted my answer to question at link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book has something on the topic now: http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#automatic_code_reloading